# divider or border thickness on a particular JavaFxTableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a TableView that has many columns. I'd like to break up the columns by including some kidn of separator or a thicker border between two columns to denote a kind of group. Something simple like a thicker column line would be fine. I am not sure how to do this in FXML or in code.

Comment: you can try per-group style classes for tableColumn

Comment: Give certain columns a CSS ID or style class. Then try to style those columns with a thicker border or padding or something.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what is mentioned in the comments. You need to include a style class to the column and define the border width.

But apart from that, I would like to let you know another important change to make it more effective. If you only adjust the border width, the end result will look as below.(included a thicker border for demonstration)

```
.thick-border{
  -fx-border-width: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

[image]

If you notice, visually the border width is applied only on the data columns and not on the column header. This definitely looks a bit odd :-) But technically this is working perfectly fine and the border width indeed is applied to column headers. The main issue is that the default border color of column header is transparent.

To fix this, you also need to include the border color to override the column header border color.

```
.thick-border{
  -fx-border-width: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  -fx-border-color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

[image]

Below is the demo of example. You can give a try by commenting the border-color part in the css file.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class TableColumnThickBorder_Demo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.getColumns().add(createCol("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty, 150));
        tableView.getColumns().add(createCol("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty, 150));
        tableView.getColumns().add(createCol("Email", Person::emailProperty, 200));

        tableView.getItems().addAll(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(tableView), 600, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("tablecolumnthickborder_demo.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ThickBorder Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TableColumn<Person, String> createCol(String title, 
            Function<Person, ObservableValue<String>> mapper, double size) {
        TableColumn<Person, String> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> mapper.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        col.setPrefWidth(size);
        if(title.equals("First Name")){
            col.getStyleClass().add("thick-border");
        }
        return col ;
    }

   public class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName");
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName");
        private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "email");

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            this.firstName.set(firstName);
            this.lastName.set(lastName);
            this.email.set(email);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return this.email;
        }
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The code in the css file:

```
.thick-border{
  -fx-border-width: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  -fx-border-color: #AAAAAA;
}
```